# Being an earning woman can’t I expect any thing from my husband?

Tags: nikah

My husband is well off and earns more than me. I contribute about half of what he does to the family and as I earn, he does not bear my expense. Being an earning woman can’t I expect any thing from my husband?

Comment: AKAIK. The husband has certain obligation towards his wife (subsistence, clothing, shelter etc) which are irrespective of the the wife's material/financial status and she *should* expect to get them.

Answer (score 3):

It is the responsibility of a husband to take care of all her needs regardless of whether she earns or not. She can only be a support him in financial difficulties. Just because she earns, does not mean he should hold back from spending on her needs.

**Reference**

Read Surah Nisa's translation.

Answer (score 0):

It's the husband's responsibility to see to the wife and the entire family's needs.
If the husband allows the wife to go and work, ALL her money is hers alone, the husband will have no say or influence on what or how the money is spent, in fact, the husband needn't know how much she earns!

whether the family is in financial difficulty or not, it is always the woman's prerogative; concerning whether she wants to help out financially or not.

- Sorry for butting into your life, but I noticed you saying your husband beats you as well.
  I studied the subject of Talaaq at High school and wrote about it to graduate and both abuse; and a shortage of financial support from the husband is grounds for divorce.

Most people don't know this, as I didn't before I learnt it, but in Islam, the husband has to support the wife up until and even after divorce;
 - the ex-wife must be clothed, fed, and should be given shelter up until the point that she finds another husband.

Of course it seems that your husband is following his own adaptation of Islam, and creates his own innovations to the laws of Allah and Allah says in the Quraan that (A'uthu billahi minashaytaanir rajeem, bismillah hirrahmaanir raheem) "Every innovation is a misguidance and every misguidance leads to the hellfire"

Allah also says in sura An-Nisa that talaaq/divorce was granted as protection for the women.

Talaaq is disliked by Allah, so I'd try and talk to your husband about getting counselling, etc.
if he refuses, try threatening with divorce and see his reaction, if it's with violence, I suggest go to your Imaam and speak about applying for divorce, 
It is disliked by Allah, but even more disliked is a marriage going bitter; you lose respect for one another even more as muslim brother and sister when things like this drag on for too long.

Allah guide you inshaa-allah.
look everything up that I've spoken about if you're unsure, Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

The are many rights that you have on your husband, many of these are decreed in the Quran, and others are from the hadith and our Prophet (PBUH) sayings. The basics are:

1. Housing
2. Clothing
3. Living Expenses
4. Education for your children

Similarly, if God forbid you are divorced, you also have some rights from your husband that he must provide for you and your children until you are re-married and that he must treat you with kindness and respect [2:228](http://quran.com/2/228).

Similarly, your husband also has some rights over you - for example that you would protect his property and your chastity [4:34](http://quran.com/4/34).

[This article](http://sunnah.org/msaec/articles/responsibilities_husband.htm) summarizes them well, I will paraphrase them here in case the link dies:

1. He cannot ask you do something against Islam.
2. He must control his passions [2:187](http://quran.com/2/187), and he must not chose to only gratify himself.
3. He must treat you generously.
4. He must protect your honor and chastity, and prevent you from being put in situations where your honor/chastity can be compromised.
5. He must not leave you in suspense for long periods of time without your consent. [4:129](http://quran.com/4/129).
6. The Prophet (PBUH) repeatedly stressed against beating of wives, and even if you were to strike them, do not strike them on their face. In fact, beating is a valid reason for divorce in Islam.

Just because you are earning money, does not exempt ***either of you*** from your rights and responsibilities under Islam.